# jQuery Insert After Append?

Tags: jquery, appendchild, appendto

I have the following HTML

```
<ul>
   <li>Some stuff first<li>
</ul>
```

Basically I am using `appendTo(ul)` to append a bunch of stuff to this but I want it to actually `append` AFTER the first child `li` ?

How can I do this ?

I've tried `.appendTo(ul).insertAfter('li:first');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to combine `appendTo` and `insertAfter`, you can just use [`insertAfter`](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/) and make the selector more specific:

```
var li = $("<li>New</li>");
li.insertAfter($("ul li:first"));
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/LGmEp/3/).

**Edit** based on comments

I think what you mean is that you already have the `ul` in a variable and would like to use that. If that's the case, you could try something like this:

```
var li = $("<li>New</li>");
li.insertAfter(ul.children().eq(0));
```

Here's an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/LGmEp/5/) of that one.

Comment: I am using the `ul` as part of a `function(ul, item)` ?

Comment: @Andy - See my edit. I think that's what you're trying to do.

Comment: why try so hard to use inserAfter when after would do it in one line, one wrapper

Comment: @Sinetheta - Using `after` really makes no difference. It would simply become `ul.children().eq(0).after(li);`. Semantically, I prefer `insertAfter`.

Comment: I would agree with you if you had been able to find your target in a single step. However, since it requires traversing from target->children->first it can't be argued that insertAfter is semantically equivalent. Burying the heavy lifting inside of a parameter passed to a method reduces the code's readability unnecessarily.

Answer (score 2):

Try using this...................

```
ul>li:first
```

Answer (score 1):

Use after() to insert after the first li.

```
$('ul li:first').after('<li>some other stuff</li>');
```

Comment: everyone threw their hats in the ring, and you were the first to hit the mark ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('ul li:first').after('<li>Some stuff second</li>')
```

Comment: that would put it INSIDE the first li

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want:

```
.insertAfter($(ul).children().first());
// should work as well:
// .insertAfter(ul.children[0])
```

or if `ul` is not a variable:

```
.insertAfter('ul > li:nth-child(1)');
```

Comment: if he's asking such a basic question, I wouldn't presume to give him code fragments which won't actually work

Comment: @Sinetheta: I'm following the style he used (`.appendTo(ul).insertAfter('li:first');`) so I'm assuming he can deal with that.